# Allow Node.js webserver to handle PHP

Tags: php, node.js, webserver

I have a web server that I created using Node.js that supports multiple file types, I'd like to integrate PHP into Node.js, so if a user wishes to use a php script, my web server will know how to handle it.

I've read up about Nginx, php.js and several other guides, wondering if anyone has any other simpler method, or has a newer node framework been created for this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I successfully created a web server had handles both JavaScript and PHP, I shall post the code as an answer with the requirements needed to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the below code, you will need php installed on the host machine and added to $PATH. Don't try to re-invent the wheel, everything you need has already been made for you, all you have to do is connect the dots.

```
var http = require("http"),
fs = require("fs"),
path = require("path"),
url = require("url"),
wildcard = require("wildcard"),
runner = require("child_process");

function sendError(errCode, errString, response)
{
  response.writeHead(errCode, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write(errString + "\n");
  response.end();
  return false;
}  

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname
    , filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

  var contentTypesByExtension = {
    '.html': "text/html",
    '.css':  "text/css",
    '.js':   "text/javascript",
    '.avi' : "video/x-msvideo",
    '.exe' : "application/octet-stream",
    '.gif' : "image/gif",
    '.htm' : "text/html",
    '.ico' : "image/x-icon",
    '.png' : "image/png",
    '.jpeg' : "image/jpeg",
    '.jpg' : "image/jpeg",
    '.mp3' : "audio/mpeg",
    '.mpeg' : "video/mpeg",
    '.pdf' : "application/pdf",
    '.sh' : "application/x-sh",
    '.snd' : "audio/basic",
    '.src' : "application/x-wais-source",
    '.svg' : "image/svg+xml",
    '.tar' : "application/x-tar",
    '.tgz' : "application/x-compressed",
    '.txt' : "text/plain",
    '.zip' : "application/zip",
    '.woff' : "application/font-woff",
    '.woff2' : "application/font-woff2"
  };

  var param = url.parse(request.url).query;

  fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {


    if(!exists) {
      response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("404 Not Found\n");
      response.end();
      return;
    }

    if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) filename += '/index.html';

    fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
        if(err) {        
            response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write(err + "\n");
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        var headers = {};
        var contentType = contentTypesByExtension[path.extname(filename)];

        if (contentType) { 
            headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;
            response.writeHead(200 + " " + headers);
            response.write(file, "binary");
            response.end(); }
        else if(filename.indexOf(".php") >= 0) {
            var tmp = filename.replace(/ /g, '\\ ');
            runner.exec("php " + tmp + " " + param, function(err, phpResponse, stderr) {
            if(err) console.log(err); /* log error */
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write( phpResponse );
            response.end();
            }); }

    });
  });
}).listen(1000);

console.log("Server started on http://localhost:1000/");
console.log("Server supports HTML, CSS, JS and PHP!");
```

Comment: That isn't going to properly support PHP. For example the `header()` function won't work, sessions won't work, and it won't have access to any of the superglobals (like `$_GET`).

Comment: Apologies yes, this piece of code will not support everything in PHP, but it will work for the basics. I would use it as a guideline for those unsure where to go for creating web servers that can handle both javascript and php.

Comment: @_GET et al *are* the basics.

Comment: Then that would be a mistake on my part for not testing the application enough for php, the program was done for a college project so it was more of a learning curve for myself.